# Why is a discriminant problem linearly separable when the hat matrix is equal to I

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis

Having a linear discriminant function that discriminate the vectors in a labelled two-class problem expressed as:

$X\theta =y$

Where $X$ is a n×m matrix, y is the vector $y= (y1,...,yN)^T$ and $\theta$ is a m*1 vector.

Why is the problem linearly separable if:

$X(X^TX)^{-1}  X^T =I$

An explanation and mathematical proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think so? A criterion for linear separability which does not involve $y$?